# Creating classes in Java

Tags: java, class, constructor

I'm trying to create a class to list information on cars. The two files I have below are CarClass.Java and Car.java.

When running CarClass.Java I am receiving one error on the "Car car1 = new Car(2018, "Black", "Chevy", "Corvette", 250);" line of code.

*error: constructor Car in class Car cannot be applied to given types;*

*required: no arguments*

*found: int,String,String,String,int*

*reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length*

*1 error*

**My question is what do I need to change in order to fix this error so my program will run properly?**

```
 import java.io.PrintStream;

public class CarClass
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Car car1 = new Car(2018, "Black", "Chevy", "Corvette", 250);


      System.out.println("The " + car1.getYear() + " " + car1.getColor() + " " + car1.getMake() + " " + car1.getModel() + "Top speed is " + car1.getSpeed() + 
      " mph.");
      }
     }



--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class Car
{
   private int carYear;
   private String carColor;
   private String carMake;
   private String carModel;
   private int carSpeed;

   public void Car(int year, String color, String make, String model, int speed)
   {


      this.carYear = year;
      this.carColor = color;
      this.carMake = make;
      this.carModel = model;
      this.carSpeed = speed;
   }

   public int getYear()
   {
   return this.carYear;
   }

   public String getColor()
   {
   return this.carColor;
   }

   public String getMake()
   {
   return this.carMake;
   }

   public String getModel()
   {
   return this.carModel;
   }

   public int getSpeed()
   {
   return this.carSpeed;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your constructor cannot have a return type. Change it to :

```
public Car(int year, String color, String make, String model, int speed) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The below statement will call the constructor of the class :

> Car car1 = new Car(2018, "Black", "Chevy", "Corvette", 250);

But then since you had mentioned a return type in the Car class it will be treated as a method by JVM

> public **void** Car(int year, String color, String make, String model, int speed)
>      {

```
  this.carYear = year;
  this.carColor = color;
  this.carMake = make;
  this.carModel = model;
  this.carSpeed = speed;
```

}

**remove the return type to solve the error !**

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a return statement in a Constructor. A Constructor is used to Initialize your object. So, you don't have the need of returning anything. Hence, the modification below should work.

```
public Car(int year, String color, String make, String model, int speed)
{
  this.carYear = year;
  this.carColor = color;
  this.carMake = make;
  this.carModel = model;
  this.carSpeed = speed;
}
```